# Can I read stream data into Apache Beam from a cometd topic using java?

Tags: java, apache-beam, google-cloud-platform, cometd

I have a producer spitting messages out on a cometd topic. I need to pick and process the stream of messages from this topic. I have probably spent last two hours trying to find a way to ingest the messages on cometd directly into apache Beam. I seem to be hitting a wall here. I know that I have following options:

1. Get from topic, Write the data to kafka and then push the data from kafka to beam.
2. Get from topic, Write the data to pub/sub on GCP and then push it through to Apache Beam.

Both the options above seem to be including an extra component in the architecture. Is there is a better way to do this? Any examples? Code Samples? Pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of anybody yet having written or started a CometD connector for Beam. The current connectors are listed at https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/. To write your own, you could try mimicking the code of one of the other basic streaming connectors, such as AMQP, MQTT or JMS (Kafka and Pubsub are very advanced and I don't advise guiding your implementation by their source code).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, yes i did have a look at the existing and upcoming integrations they have available. I was also probably looking for the approach confirmation as to whether the best idea would be to go forward with implementing a connector or some being able to use another component in between?

Comment: Confirming: there is currently no good way to pull data from a streaming source without implementing your own UnboundedSource. https://beam.apache.org/blog/2017/08/16/splittable-do-fn.html will eventually make this better. There may be special cases where you can get away with just piggybacking on GenerateSequence.from(0) and applying a ParDo that ignores every element and pulls a message from cometd, but that will not have proper fault tolerance behavior, e.g. if cometd has the concept of acking, you won't be able to ack at the right time, and in case of retries the data will be lost.

Comment: Thank you @jkff :)